# No XAML UI designing tool in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

Can't get XAML files open in any UI designer. Any choice makes them open in a text editor. XAML designer flag is enabled in options. Couldnt find any helpful answer on this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xamarin.Forms doesn't have a designer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97303/where-are-the-xaml-designer-tools), you have to write XAML on your own and use Previewer Tools ([Xamarin Hotreload](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanislavBavtovich.hotreloadxamarinforms), [LiveXAML](http://www.livexaml.com/), [XAMLator](https://github.com/ylatuya/XAMLator/)) to preview the XAML changes you do until you think the UI looks good.